# Let user schedule time for not receiving remote push notification

Tags: ios, parse-platform, apple-push-notifications

I'm developing an iOS app that uses Push Notifications from Parse. Is it possible to let user to schedule the time for receiving push notification. For example, the user may want to mute/disable the push notification from 00:00 to 07:00 everyday. 
You may assume there will be remote notification only.

Is it possible to create such a setting to mute the push notification programmatically on the client side?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you can disable the push notification from the system settings during the disable time user will not get notification

Comment: @Pyro You mean the system app of iOS? But I want the user do it once and for all. Not doing it once everyday. If I miss understood you, please show me how. thx a lot

Answer (score 0):

I don't know  if there are any automated process for it , i have knowledge of the manual process to stop the push notification

**1st way**: GO to device settings -> your app -> Notifications(if you have taken permission from user to show the notification, it will show in the settings), inside it looks like this 
[image]

if user disable this `Allow Notifications` options user will not get notifications for particular app, but to enable the push notification user has to follow the same steps and enable the push notification from the settings only

**2nd way** in the application there is a method called `unregisterForRemoteNotifications` which can stop the push notifications programatically but i am not getting idea how we can automate register/unregister this during the user selected period of time

Comment: The 2nd way is the point. Let's go back to the example I mentioned in the question. Suppose the app is not running, how can I call unregisterForRN at 00:00 and I register back at 07:00. It seems impossible, so I'm looking a workaround.